# out of Memory Error while printing a string

Tags: java, android

I have a problem that I am facing OuOfMemory Error while printing a string after encoding bytes into String through Base64 encoder. Here are the following Code related details:

**Error Stack:**

```
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:89)
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.<init>(StringBuffer.java:83)
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660):     at com.example.TestCryptoActivity.onCreate(TestCryptoActivity.java:54)
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-05 12:25:30.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2660):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Code(The Last line of the code is responsible for the error):**

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/E0022505.mp4");
        try {
               is = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
               e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] fileData = new byte[2097152];
        int read = 0;
        while(read != fileData.length) {
           try {
            read += is.read(fileData, read, fileData.length - read);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bos.write(fileData,0,read);

        bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        StringBuffer strNew = new StringBuffer(Base64.encodeToString(fileData, 0));
        System.out.println("The bytes array:"+strNew);---> This line makes error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing those three lines that don't do anything useful would at least avoid at least 2097152 bytes in memory :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bos.write(fileData,0,read);
bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

For the rest, this code causes the exception to happen, but it's maybe because some other part of the code, executed before is too memory-hungry.

Try using a profiler to detect where the memory is used.

But storing a whole large byte array, along with its copy encoded in base64, in memory in an android program is of course a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

So let me get this straight. You have a roughly 2MB file and you want to base64-encode (so it will turn into something like 2.7MB) it and then print it out.

Why? Seriously. Are you going to check every byte of the output?

I would suggest something more along the lines of:

```
System.out.println ("The bytes array:" + strNew.substring (0, 50));
```

so you can at least check it without blowing up the output.

There's a fairly good chance that your JRE (or Davlik in this case) doesn't particularly *like* the idea of multi-megabyte strings (since `StringBuilder` is where everything is falling apart here).

If that *still* doesn't help, you can segment your base64 encoding so as to not end up with huge strings. Base64 turns `3n` bytes into `4n` bytes so, if you process segments that are a multiple of 3, you won't have to worry about alignment issues. For example, process your 2M byte array in 3K chunks - each of those will give a 4K base64-encoded chunk for you to do something with. And this chunking will reduce the likelihood of running out of memory.

Comment: Actually Pax, the video which I have is DRM video in which 2^21 bytes are encrypted and I have to decrypt it with the help of SHA-512 Hash key generation and replace that 2^21 bytes with the generated Hash. That's why I have to get the same

Comment: @Sanat, that's fine, I just question the need to print it out. _That's_ where your problem lies here, the fact that you're StringBuilding a massive string for the unnecessary `println`.

Comment: Thanx Pax for your valuable answer

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is not specially made for use in Android device so it never think for memory utilization and the String will be so long size when we are encoding video files and sometimes big images too,and we have a limited Hip Size(arroung 25MB) the memory get out of size.

I have encountered the same issue many times and i am sure others have too while uploading the large files to server in Base64 encoding this is the damn hard possible thing..and in my case i never get successed

I Advice you to change your server to accept the data in byte array else then in Base64..
and while sending the file to server in bytes use multi-part..the useful library to do that is **[http-mime4.1.1.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpmime411jar.htm)**

I have read documentation and blogs for this issue and spent many days searching the solution..but there's no way to work with Base64 having limited memory.If u programmatically overcome the OOM error in this case that will come while sending the post request to the server.